# How can I pass cookie from one page to another which the two pages are not in the same directory?

Tags: php, cookies

I have one server but two directories for example:

> - www
>
>   - Directory1
>
>     - index.php
>     - page1.php
>     - page2.php
>   - Directory2
>
>     - index.php
>     - page3.php
>     - page4.php

When I want to transfer from the page `index.php` of `Directory1` to the page `index.php` of `Directory2`, how can I pass the cookies set in the page `index.php` of `Directory1` using PHP?

Comment: You don't have to do anything... PHP will automatically set the `$_COOKIE` array with the existing cookies. Cookies are not dependent upon a single PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to PHP documentation

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

```
$time = time() + 3600;
setcookie('foo', 'bar', $time, "/");
```

when you set the fourth parameter i.e `path` as `/`, it will be accessible to you on the domain level, and i guess that is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `path` parameter:

```
setcookie("name", "value", time() + 3600, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set the optional Path parameter, and then it is available to both directories.

Comment: My mistake, the default is current directory, set to "/" as others answered.